# efficient query by slug (not as id)

Tags: sql, mongodb, performance, database

Does anybody know how to make efficient query against slug.
For example when you search in stackoverflow, you write array of keywords. In the database you have slug (which is not id) from exact/similar keywords like C#-programming-database-api.
Is there any efficient way to search "slug" field with combination of keywords considering large number of entries (million). I'm using mongodb (but that isn't important)

Thx